# Custom field for devise on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have installed devise gem and added custom fields to database for `fullname` and `location` as strings.

I updated `edit` and `new` form pages as:

```
<%= f.input :fullname, required: true %>
<%= f.input :location %>
```

But it doesn't save or update this fields.

I can't see any controller for that
[image]

What am I missing? I went through tens of tutorials, but can't figure it out.

I'm using Rails 5.1.3 and Ruby 2.4.0p0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the "lazy way" by using the `configure_permitted_parameters` before filter.

In your ApplicationController add the protected method specifying the keys to permit in the `devise_parameter_sanitizer`. Then add a before_action callback pointing to this method if the controller being used is a devise registered controller.

In your case maybe something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    permit_attrs(%i[fullname location])
  end

  def permit_attrs(attrs)
    %i[sign_up account_update].each do |action|
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(action, keys: attrs)
    end
  end
end
```